# rdp though reverse ssh tunnel with extra hop

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-desktop, tunnel

I'm currently struggling with this task:

Changing Windows machines have to RDP over SSH to a Raspberry behind changing foreign networks.

So there has to be machine in-between the Windows host and the Raspberry.

I setup a Linux VM in our DMZ and also the FW policies + NAT rules.

Things that work:

- I can reverse SSH from the Raspberry to the Linux VM in the DMZ
- When Windows and Raspberry are in the same network, RDP over SSH works

Things that I can't figure out:

Tunnel RDP through Linux VM through reverse SSH tunnel to the Raspberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more into this I figured it out!

Raspberry:

ssh -N -T -R33898:localhost:3389 Linux-VM

Windows (using putty):

Destination: Linux-VM:22

SSH > Tunnels> Forwarded ports: L4444 localhost:33898

Comment: So with this do you see from windows your raspberry using RDP? Or the opposite? Do you see your windows RDP from raspberry?

Comment: @realtebo RDP from Windows making a hop on a Linux VM to get to the raspberry

The post is 3 years old though, so don't know details anymore